# encoding gives two different output?

Tags: java

There is two classes:

key.java and test.java

in the test.java the expected outcome is ascii value of a + 5 = f? which does get outputted but when i run it the line:

```
System.out.println(k1.encode('G')); // expected output 'L'
```

outputs not the ascii value of G plus 5, it outputs: lower case e?

i am getting to the end of my threshold here, why?

key.java:

```
class Key{
    private int value;

    Key(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public char encode(char c){
        if (isValidKey(value) == true) {
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
                c = (char)(( c - 'a' + value) % 26 + 'a');
            }else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
                c = (char)(( c - 'A' + value) % 26 + 'A');
            }else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                c = (char)(( c - '0' + value) % 10 + '10');
            } else {
                return '.';
            }
            return c;
        }

        public char decode(char c){
            if (isValidKey(value) == true) {
                if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
                    c = (char)(( c - 'a' - value) % 26 + 'a');
                }else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
                    c = (char)(( c - 'A' - value) % 26 + 'A');
                }else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                    c = (char)(( c - '0' - value) % 10 + '10');

                }else{
                    return'.';
                }

                return c;

            }

            public static boolean isValidKey(int value){
                if (value >= 0 && value <= 25){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**test.java:**

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Key k1,k2;
        k1=new Key(5);
        k2=new Key(15);

        String s="This is a test. Let's see if that works";
        String t=Cryptic.encrypt(s,k1);
        System.out.println("Original: "+s);
        System.out.println("Encoded with k1: "+t);
        System.out.println("The result ddecoded with k1: "+Cryptic.decrypt(t,k1));

        //individual tests

        System.out.println(Key.isValidKey(5)); // the expected output is true

        System.out.println(Key.isValidKey(25)); // the expected output is true
        System.out.println(Key.isValidKey(-1)); // the expected output is false
        System.out.println(Key.isValidKey(-10)); // the expected output is false
        System.out.println(Key.isValidKey(200)); // the expected output is false
        System.out.println(Key.isValidKey(1)); // the expected output is true

        Key k3= new Key(-1);

        System.out.println(k1.encode('a')); // expected output 'f'
        System.out.println(k2.encode('a')); // expected output 'p'
        System.out.println(k1.encode('7')); // expected output '2'
        System.out.println(k3.encode('a')); // expected output '.'
        System.out.println(k3.encode('7')); // expected output '.'

        System.out.println(k1.decode('a')); // expected output 'v'
        System.out.println(k2.decode('a')); // expected output 'l'
        System.out.println(k1.decode('7')); // expected output '2'
        System.out.println(k3.decode('a')); // expected output '.'
        System.out.println(k3.decode('7')); // expected output '.'

        System.out.println(k1.encode('G')); // expected output 'L'
        System.out.println(k1.decode('G')); // expected output 'B'
        System.out.println(k1.encode('*')); // expected output '*'

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm surprised your Key class even compiles. '10' is an invalid character constant in my eclipse.

Comment: Yes. '10' is not a char. This code does not compile.  Also, encode method has bad brace matching.  Same for decode method.  What is class `Cryptic`?

Comment: @user3042332 I tried to fix the indentation of your code and you appear to be missing multiple closing braces. Can you please update your code to something that compiles?

Comment: @benjamin.d don't be surprised cause it ***doesn't*** compile: missing closing brackets, using `'10'` as a char, missing `return` statements...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     public char encode(char c){
         if (isValidKey(value) == true) {
             if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
                  c = (char)(( c - 'a' + value) % 26 + 'a');
             }else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
                 c = (char)(( c - 'A' + value) % 26 + 'A');
             }else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                 c = (char) ( c + value);
                 if(c>57) 
                     c-=10;
             }
         } else {
             return '.';
         }
         return c;
     }
```